# I'm generating a Google Street View URL that works in Chrome but not Internet Explorer. What's wrong?

Tags: maps, google, url

I've made a small add-in in ArcGIS that allows a user to open their current GIS view in Google Maps and also to select a location to open in Street View. The map view works in both IE11 and Chrome. The street view works in Chrome, however when opened in IE it gets redirected.

For example, the generated URL might be: 
https://www.google.com/maps?cbll=-36.0851437761,146.917419491&cbp=12,90,0,0,5&layer=c
Which when opened in IE gets redirected to:
www.google.com/maps/@/data=!3m3!1e1!3m1!2e0
Which then gets redirected to:
www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,7z

The only solution I can think of (but am unable to currently test - I don't have administrator privileges) is that maybe Google Maps needs to be added to the list of trusted sites in the privacy settings. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: I get the same street-view (picture of a bus, South Albury NSW) whether I open that URL in IE11 or in Chrome.  The URL in the address bar looks more like your IE example in both IE and in Chrome (and are identical in both).  I don't have Google maps as a trusted site in either browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've also been able to confirm that it's working on other machines in IE11 just fine, so it must be an issue on my end.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question, are you saying that after being redirected, the URL doesn't work, or are you asking why there is a redirection for one, but not the other?  I'm using Firefox, I also get redirected, but the the street view works for me too (which is I think the main thing).  Is the redirection causing you a problem for some reason, or putting that anther way why do you need to solve the problem of a redirection if the net effect is the same?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The link redirects to http://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,7z which presents a blank page. The coordinates in the link are several thousand kilometres away from the original link's location. The problem is that whenever opened in IE, the link redirection seems to disregard any information in the original link I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. Make sure Google Maps is not in 'Lite Mode'. If it is, switch to 'full Google Maps' using the lightning bolt button at the bottom of the maps window.